# Calculating variance between raster layers using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000989

I have raster data that I would like to calculate the variance for different height stratas, ex. 05_10_cov represents density values for height strata between 5 and 10 feet and block_07_avg represents the average of all height strata.

I want to calculate my layers as so

((Square("00_05_cov" - "block_07_avg") + Square("05_10_cov" - "block_07_avg") + Square("10_15_cov" - "block_07_avg") + Square("15_20_cov" - "block_07_avg") + Square("20_25_cov" - "block_07_avg")) / (5-1)

However, raster calculator doesn't allow for this formatting. What I have above is the actual equation for variance (something that would work in excel for instance), and I just can't figure out how to make it raster calculator friendly. I know this is a formatting issue and I'm not sure what the proper format is (not python savvy).

> ERROR 000989 : Python syntax error: .

Comment: Are those raster layers? How have you attempted to run that expression? Why did it not work? Edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Yes, those are all raster layers.The error was 000989 : Python syntax error: <value>: The code block used by the Calculate Field or Calculate Value tool has a syntax error. This error message provided will list the specific Python syntax error.

Comment: This error code covers a number of Python syntax errors, for example, Parsing error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (line 3). 

The above is a Python syntax error. Line 3 has invalid indentation. For specific Python issues, consult the Python documentation for more information, or consult the Calculate Field, Calculate Value, or Analyze Tools For Pro help for more information on these tools.

When returned by a script tool or when evaluating a script tool using Analyze Tools For Pro, this error can also indicate that the tool's source script cannot be found.

Comment: Use the raster calculator tool, calculate field tool is for tables such as a featureclass.

Comment: Also despite me asking you to EDIT YOUR QUESTION you have shoved all this information into comments... It become tiresome for other users to trawl though the comments when in reality this important information should have been in your original question.

Comment: first time commenter. never used this website. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: I am using the raster calculator tool as stated in the question and title. This is a part of a per cell statistical analysis.

Comment: ok, can you edit your question and actually show a screen shot of you calling the raster calculator tool as the error would suggest you are using the wrong tool?